# C# Set Method equivalent in Objective-C

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c

I am porting a small function from C# to Objective-C (for the iPhone), and I am running into a snag with a C# method.

I'm not sure what the following C# lines would equate to in Objective C. **Particularly the `Set` Method**.

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(DESC_LEN);

bits.Set(j,
(ii_data[cix_1 - KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step - KERNEL_SZ/2] +
 ii_data[cix_1 + KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step + KERNEL_SZ/2] -
 ii_data[cix_1 - KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step + KERNEL_SZ/2] -
 ii_data[cix_1 + KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step - KERNEL_SZ/2])
 >
(ii_data[cix_2 - KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step - KERNEL_SZ/2] +
 ii_data[cix_2 + KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step + KERNEL_SZ/2] -
 ii_data[cix_2 - KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step + KERNEL_SZ/2] -
 ii_data[cix_2 + KERNEL_SZ/2*ii_step - KERNEL_SZ/2] )
);
```

Does anyone have any idea what Set in C# might equate to in Objective-C. Of course I've done some Googling, but nothing pops out.

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a way to implement bit arrays in Objective-C.  There is an answer to that question here: [How do I implement a bit array in C / Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744304/how-do-i-implement-a-bit-array-in-c-objective-c).

As for what the `Set` method does, the documentation for that is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.set.aspx.  All it does is set the bit at the given index (in this case `j`) with a boolean value (in this case, the result of the inequality comparison).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a very brief search, it looks like BitArray isn't a natural part of Objective C.  So, you should first tell us what you're trying to use in place of C#'s BitArray.

This question may help: [How do I implement a bit array in C / Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744304/how-do-i-implement-a-bit-array-in-c-objective-c)