# Bit Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bit

When working with Project Euler problems I often need large (> 10**7) bit array's.

My normal approach is one of:

```
bool* sieve = new bool[N];

bool sieve[N];
```

When N = 1,000,000 my program uses 1 MegaByte (8 * 1,000,000 bits).

Is there a more efficient way to use store bit arrays than bool in c++?

Comment: i implement sieve's algorithm using vectors.. it can hold that many numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ efficient bit array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633400/c-c-efficient-bit-array)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) (if `N` is a constant) otherwise use `std::vector<bool>` as others have mentioned (but dont forget reading [this excellent article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm) by Herb Sutter)

> A bitset is a special container class that is designed to store bits (elements with only two possible values: 0 or 1, true or false, ...).
>
> The class is very similar to a regular array, **but optimizing for space allocation**: each element occupies only one bit (which is eight times less than the smallest elemental type in C++: char).

**EDIT**:

Herb Sutter (in that article) mentions that

> The reason std::vector< bool > is nonconforming is that it pulls tricks under the covers in an attempt to optimize for space: Instead of storing a full char or int for every bool[1] (taking up at least 8 times the space, on platforms with 8-bit chars), *it packs the bools and stores them as individual bits*(inside, say, chars) in its internal representation.
>
> std::vector < bool > **forces** a specific optimization on all users by enshrining it in the standard. That's not a good idea; different users have different requirements, and now all users of vector must pay the performance penalty even if they don't want or need the space savings.

**EDIT 2**:

And if you have used Boost you can use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)(if `N` is known at runtime)

Comment: Sadly the link to the Sutter article is dead by 24-11-2021.

Comment: @GergelyMáté, it is available today (2023-01-05).

Answer (score 15):

For better or for worse, `std::vector<bool>` will use bits instead of bool's, to save space. So just use `std::vector` like you should have been in the first place.

*If `N` is a constant*, you can use `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 5):

You could look up `std::bitset` and `std::vector<bool>`. The latter is often recommended against, because despite the `vector` in the name, it doesn't really act like a vector of any other kind of object, and in fact doesn't meet the requirements for a container in general. Nonetheless, it can be pretty useful.

OTOH, nothing is going to (at least dependably) store 1 million bool values in less than 1 million bits. It simply can't be done with any certainty. If your bit sets contain a degree of redundancy, there are various compression schemes that might be effective (e.g., LZ*, Huffman, arithmetic) but without some knowledge of the contents, it's impossible to say they would be for certain. Either of these will, however, normally store each bool/bit in only one bit of storage (plus a *little* overhead for bookkeeping -- but that's usually a constant, and on the order of bytes to tens of bytes at most).

Answer (score 4):

A 'bool' type isn't stored using only 1 bit. From your comment about the size, it seems to use 1 entire byte for each bool.

A C like way of doing this would be:

```
uint8_t sieve[N/8]; //array of N/8 bytes
```

and then logical OR bytes together to get all your bits:

```
sieve[0] = 0x01 | 0x02; //this would turn on the first two bits
```

In that example, 0x01 and 0x02 are hexadecimal numbers that represent bytes.

Comment: upvoted, good idea, may be, it's N/8+1, it's bit packed array.

Answer (score 3):

A 'bool' type isn't stored using only 1 bit. From your comment about the size, it seems to use 1 entire byte for each bool.

A C like way of doing this would be:

```
uint8_t sieve[N/8]; //array of N/8 bytes
```

element of array is:

```
result = sieve[index / 8] || (1 << (index % 8));
```

or

```
result = sieve[index >> 3] || (1 << (index & 7));
```

set 1 in array:

```
sieve[index >> 3] |= 1 << (index & 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in trying the [BITSCAN](https://www.biicode.com/pablodev/pablodev/bitscan/master) library as an alternative. Recently an extension has been proposed for sparseness, which I am not sure is your case, but might be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a byte array and index into that. Index `n` would be in byte index `n/8`, bit # `n%8`. (In case std::bitset is not available for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

If N is known at compile time, use [std::bitset](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html), otherwise use [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).